# label text not displaying correct value but messagebox.show does

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

I have a simple label in C#.NET that does not seem to be "updating". It displays only the first initial values of my application. In the following code, the "score" variable does not update however it shows the correct value when the messagebox.show dialog is called. The score value is changed in a different thread, but I don't believe it to be a problem of invokes and cross thread form control (as I am calling this code in the thread that label6 was created on).

Does anyone know what might be a solution? I tried the Application.DoEvents() method with no avail. Also, neither label6.Update() nor label6.Refresh() seem to work when placed after the label6.Text = score line.

Player is a class I created holding the score value as a public int.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        createGame();
    }
    public void createGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drawThread = new Thread(draw);  
        MessageBox.Show(player.score);
        label6.Text = player.score;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        //do drawing, change player.score value
        //end thread
    }
    public void button_click()
    {
        if(firstrun)
            drawThread.Start()
        else{
            createGame()
            drawThread.Start()
        }

    }
```

EDIT (from comments): 
This is a WinForms application.
The label6.Text = score line is the ONLY instance where label6 is called other than being instantiated in the Form.Designer code generated by Visual Studio.

Comment: OK, what is your main thread doing, then, when it should be handling repaint etc. messages?

Comment: Is this a WinForms app?  Web Application? etc.?

Comment: One - typically you never want to call `Application.DoEvents` from your code. Second, Are you sure other code isnt coming in behind this guy and setting the label text to something else?

Comment: Have you tried calling Update on the label? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx

Comment: Probably your label doesn't get updated because main thread is busy and cannot process message queue. Can you show us more code please?

Comment: +1 for @Tejs for rejecting the CPU-wasting recursion-generator.

Comment: I think code will be usefull to check from where you are getting value in MessageBox and Label...

Comment: Well, if you comment out the draw.Start after the createGame(), is the label Text change then rendered OK?

Answer (score 2):

just do `Refresh()` on the label.

```
label6.Refresh();
```

Comment: if `Application.DoEvents()` does not process queue, why `label.Refresh()` should solve problem?

Comment: Is this not done automagically when the Text property is set?

Comment: @MartinJames: no, when you update Text property, probably canvas is invalidated... but until main thread process message queue and perform a repaint, control remains with old value...

Comment: @Marco - yes, I understand that the resulting Windows messages must get processed before these changed properties can be actually rendered onto the display.

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see

```
drawThread = new Thread(draw);
```

but on button click you call `draw.Start()` so I think your rendering thread is not started at all! Shouldn't you use `drawThread.Start()`?
More: you cannot access graphical controls properties from a thread different from the main, you should use `Invoke`...

I see a problem here:

1. `drawThread = new Thread(draw);

   MessageBox.Show(player.score);`
   With these lines second thread is started and MessageBox is showed immediately (second thread is not terminated yet probably)
2. `label6.Text = player.score;`
   When you close MessageBox this line is executed: if second thread is terminated and has already updated score you will get expected result; if second thread is still executing, in your label you still find previous score.

So without knowing what your second thread does, I cannot know if your code is correct or not.
In my opinion you should update `label6.Text` from your second thread (using `Invoke`) when it's terminated; if not, why are you using a second thread?
Usually we use threads to perform long executions without blocking main thread (which takes care of updating form and process user input), so you should update properties from these threads when it's needed.
Think about using [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: The graphical controls are not being accessed by the draw Thread. The drawThread updates a value (score) in a separate class. The label.text is redrawn in the main thread it was created in.

Comment: I have fixed what you were describing in my original post. draw.Start() was a typo from me copying my code over. It is actually drawThread.Start()